# Unity3D C# : Cursor keeps being pulled back to the center of the screen?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have been trying to solve this for 3 days now and I have been unable to solve it myself. What is happening is when I open my inventory, my mouse is in theory supposed to be shown and unlocked. Now this almost works, except when I try to actually move my mouse around, it almost instantly gets pulled (like it has a lot of gravity) straight to the center. I am using Unity version 5.4.0f3 and I am on Windows 10.Also if it makes any difference, I am using the Unity Standard Assets FPSController (but I don't think it does since locking and unlocking my cursor works just fine except in the case of using my inventory), and this is all happening in the editor.

My code that does this (in the inventory script) is:

```
 if (isShown) { // If the inventory is opened

             Cursor.visible = true;
             Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.None;
 }
```

I have no other code that affects the cursor except for this in a separate script:

```
 if (inventory.isShown || pauseManager.isPaused) { // If inventory is opened or game is paused
     Cursor.visible = true;
     Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.None;
     } else {
         Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.None;
     }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated ~

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only thing that I can think of is that your Update() is calling a part of your FPS controller(which re-locks the cursor to to the middle of the screen) even when your in the inventory or pause menu. You say that your mouse acts like it has lots of gravity or something, that is probably do to the fact that your mouse is not locked for a split second until it reaches whatever part of code that re-locks it to the center of the screen again. Check your Update() function within the script and see if you're calling anything before your if statement that you listed, that might cause that behavior. Hope this helps!

Comment: Found that the FPS controllers' mouse script was telling it to lock. Thank you so much!

Comment: Awesome, glad you figured it out. Happy coding!